# Time out/fade delay on hover div mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that, when you hover over it, another one shows up in it's place.

However, when you `mouseout` of the `div` the other `div` disappears as well.

I need the `div` that shows up to hang around long enough for a mouse to be dragged over to it and then once the mouse is on the appeared `div`, it needs to stay visible so you can click links and read text, and then disappear on `mouseout`.

I'm sure this can be done in JavaScript, but I can't figure out how to do it.

If it makes much of a difference, which I'm sure it might, it's going on a JCINK forum, so JavaScript might be limited. If there's any way to do it in CSS, that would be even better.

```
#a:hover + #b {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
#c:hover ~ #d {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
#e:hover + #f {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
#g:hover ~ #h {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
```

This is the CSS I am using currently to achieve my hover.

My javascript currently looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
document.getElementById('b').onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById('a').style.opacity=1;
}

document.getElementById('b').onmouseout = function(){
    document.getElementById('a').style.opacity=0;
} 


$('#a').hover(
  function(){
       $('#d').css('opacity', '1')
   }, 
   function() { 
       $('#d').css('opacity', '')

});

</script>
```

Comment: If you can make a minimal working example at jsfiddle, it would help a lot. Otherwise have a look at the [`transition-delay` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and as mentioned if possible create a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I did use the transition delay to stall the hover long enough to get the mouse on to it, but obviously, after the 3 seconds have gone by or whatever it is, the div continues it's fade out transition. The delay is fine, but after I get the mouse on to it, the transition needs to stop until they move the mouse away again. I'm sorry if that doesn't make much sense. I can't make a jsfiddle right now, as I am on a limited internet connection and the website is blocked.

Comment: In your current javascript, the second selection will make the overlay disappear when you mouse out of the initial div. You might want to get element "a" and apply the onmouseout attribute to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a CSS class, say `.fade` (with CSS code for transitions etc.), go along this way

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<div class="main">I'll host the hovering div</div>
<div class="hidden fade">Overlay content</div>
```

JavaScript Code -

```
var mainDiv = document.querySelector('div.main');
var hoverDiv = document.querySelector('div.hidden');

mainDiv.addEventListener('mouseover',
function() {
  hoverDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');

  var h = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('hidden');
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout',h,false);
  }

  hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseout',h,false);
},false);
```

---

Edit

---

http://jsfiddle.net/XDgmD/2/

```
body {
    background-color: silver;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px yellow;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.fade {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
}
```

---

```
var mainDiv = document.querySelector('div.main');
var hoverDiv = document.querySelector('div.hidden');

mainDiv.addEventListener('mouseover',
function() {
  hoverDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');

  var h = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('hidden');
    this.removeEventListener('mouseout',h,false);
  }

  hoverDiv.addEventListener('mouseout',h,false);
},false);
```

---

```
<div class="main">I'll host the hovering div</div>
<div class="hidden fade">Overlay content</div>
```

Comment: I've edited in my currently javascript to the original question. How would I add this in to my current set up?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe how you plan to include / use it in the forum? I think, that if you can embed HTML and/or CSS, you can do inline JS as well.

Instead of the 'hover' attribute, I would instead use the 'onmouseover' attribute for entry and 'onmouseout' attribute for exit, and point it to a simple javascript method that will change the visibility of the overlay DIV.

```
<!-- An example of the existing tab -->
<div id="existing" onmouseover="showDiv(popUpDivId);">

<!-- An example of the popup tab, with display=None set first -->
<div id="popUpDivId onmouseout="showDiv(popUpDivId);" display="None">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showDiv(popUpDivId){
        // Change the visibility. 
        $.(popUpDivId).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

I'm using jQuery here, for the [toggle() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp). I'm not sure what all and where you can call. If you can't use jQuery, instead you'd want to use the longer `document.getElementById(popUpDivId)` then change the property:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showDiv(popUpDivId){
        // Change the visibility alternative method
        var popUp = document.getElementById(popUpDivId);

        if (popUp.display == 'None') { popUp.display = 'Block'; }
        if (popUp.display == 'Block') { popUp.display = 'None'; }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using it for a pop up box where when you hover over one tab, the staff links show up, and in the div that shows up, there needs to be links that are clickable. Then the next tab down is news and so on. It's in the header of the website.

Comment: I added the second example as the script bit without the jQuery. This would go directly in the HTML file. If you can edit the HTML for the buttons, you can add the event listeners (onmouseover and onmouseout) directly. If not, another small function can be added to select each of the necessary buttons and add the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If i am infering the HTML correctly from your CSS then you should probably put the `#b`,`#d` etc elements inside their relevant `:hover` trigger.. (*and change the css accordingly..*)

This way, the hover on the inner elements that appear will still be inside the outer hovered element (*and it will not trigger the mouseout*)..